# "Adept at" versus "adept in"

Tags: difference, word-difference

Is there any difference between *adept at* and *adept in*? Should you believe it utterly depends on the context, I would be grateful if you would at least provide a brief explanation of how it depends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in this [Google Ngram search](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adept%20at,%20adept%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *adept in* is the more archaic usage, while *adept at* is more modern.

Furthermore, adept was historically used as a noun, as in: "He is an adept in the game of chess."  Currently, adept is more commonly used as an adjective, as in: "He is adept at the game of chess."

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oxford Collocations Dictionary for Sudents, you supposed to use "adept at"

adept adj.
• VERBS be, seem | become
• ADV extremely, highly, very | quite
• PREP. at "He was highly adept at avoiding trouble."

Comment: The other answer is correct: "adept at" is not wrong, but it is not the only right usage, either.

Comment: Yes. You need to be careful; non-entry in a dictionary does not mean* that a word or usage is necessarily incorrect. Dictionaries aren't identical. Even OED gives this caveat* about the portion of the lexicon it gives definitions for.